# Remove characters from Message field in splunk

Tags: regex, eval, splunk, rex

I am searching for specific event codes in splunk, such that the first part of the message field starts with `"A member was added to a security-enabled global group"`. After that, it has a whole lot more information which, for my purposes, I do not need to see. I tried the following searches however I am not getting the results I want.

This search made no changes to the message:

```
index="win_evt" EventCode=4728  | rex field=Message "(?<=A:)(?<Notes>.*)(?=.)" | table  _time, Account_Name, Group_Name, Message, EventCode, Message
```

This search completely removed the message:

```
index="win_evt" EventCode=4728  | eval Message = trim(replace(Message,".*","")) | table  _time, Account_Name, Group_Name, Message, EventCode, Message
```

This does nothing as well:

```
index="win_evt" EventCode=4728  | rex field=Message mode=sed "s/\..*$//" | table  _time, Account_Name, Group_Name, Message, EventCode, Message
```

All I want is for the `| table Message` to show is that first line.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post a sample event to help explain what you are doing.

Assuming that this `rex` is correct, `| rex field=Message "(?<=A:)(?<Notes>.*)(?=.)"`, this is placing the extracted data into a new field, called `Notes`. In your `table` command, you have the fields `_time, Account_Name, Group_Name, Message, EventCode, Message`. I think you should replace `Message` with `Notes`, so your search should be

`index="win_evt" EventCode=4728  | rex field=Message "(?<=A:)(?<Notes>.*)(?=.)" | table  _time, Account_Name, Group_Name, Message, EventCode, Notes`

Or just the following should suffice

`index="win_evt" EventCode=4728  | rex field=Message "^(?<firstline>.*)" | table  _time, Account_Name, Group_Name, firstline, EventCode`